# $AB - BA$ can't equal to Unit matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of order $n$. Show that $AB - BA$ can never be equal to unit matrix.

How to approach above question. Please help.

Comment: This does not hold in infinite dimensional settings and is crucial for quantum mechanics. It's a very interesting and surprising phenomenon.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: take the trace of $AB-BA$ and compare with the trace of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I know this one from my Linear Algebra course. **hint:** Take a look at the trace of the matrix $X = AB - BA$.